# Why the electric field is uniform by distance as 2 dielectrics exists?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, vector-fields, dielectric

[image]

The 2 dielectrics have been touched each other of border of plane as like in the diagram.

$$  \epsilon_{1} :=\text{permittivity of upper dielectric}   $$

$$  \epsilon_{2} :=\text{permittivity of lower dielectric}   $$

And the conductive sphere(radius=$a$) has been sandwitched with center of the sphere which is a point of subset of the plane of the border of the dielectrics.

We will observe what happens as charge $Q$ is given to the conductive sphere.

Concretely we want to know the distribution of the charges and the capacitance of the conductive sphere  as $Q$ is given.

The electric lines of force are flown radially.

Currently I can't get the below equation of electric field.

$$  V_{r}:=\frac{  k  }{  r  } :=\text{potential as distance from the center of the sphere is } r $$

$$  E_{r}  = -\frac{  \partial V  }{ \partial r   }  =\frac{  k  }{  r ^{2}   } :=\text{ electric field as the distance is  } r $$

$$  \epsilon_{1} E = D_{1} :=\text{ electric flux density of upper domain. }  $$

$$  \epsilon_{2} E = D_{2} :=\text{ electric flux density of upper domain. }  $$

Why $E_{r}$ can be determined uniformly as constant distance whatever in the dielectric?

I thought that as the dielectric is different, the intensity of the electric field must be different generally.

What I've been missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine that the sphere exists at infinity and the surface of it takes zero potential.

Nextly, imagine the operation which bring the test charge from the top surface of the sphere at the infinity to the conductive sphere.

After the operation, we get the 2 potentials, one of them is the reference potential(zero volt) and the other is the potential at the conductor.

Nextly,we imagine the operation which brings the test charge from the bottom of the surface of the sphere at the infinity toward the conductor.

As 2nd operation is done , we get the 2 potentials and these are exactly the same ones as first operation is done.

Hence we can conclude that the same function of electric field is used in both operations to gain the voltage.